# vb.net html parser with css query (kind of like nokogiri)

Tags: html, vb.net

Is there a tool in vb.net / for vb.net like nokogiri (a ruby gem) that allows
one to parse HTML files using the awesomeness of css queries (e.g `#htmlid`) for `<p id="htmlid">...</p>` so that I can parse html content easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) may be what you are looking for.

> CsQuery - .C# jQuery Port for .NET 4
>
> CsQuery is a jQuery port for .NET 4. It implements all CSS2 & CSS3 selectors, all the DOM manipulation methods of jQuery, and some of the utility methods. The majority of the jQuery test suite (as of 1.6.2) has been ported to C#.

If you are comfortable with LINQ and/or XPath I would also recommend the awesome [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).